# How do I get a CD version of El Capitan suitable for a Macbook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, mac-appstore, restore, macos, repair

I have 2 Macs, and am downloading El Capitan from the app store.  I want to see if I can install it on an older MacBook Pro that has a broken Command-R feature that prevents me from installing the OS.  (It says contact apple support)

Since that costs $, I'd rather see if I can simply boot and reinstall the OS in a clean way.

How do I locate and burn the downloaded El Capitan in a way that will make it bootable on the other mac?

Comment: http://www.macworld.com/article/2981585/operating-systems/how-to-make-a-bootable-os-x-10-11-el-capitan-installer-drive.html

Comment: You'll need a dual-layer DVD to fit it, or use a USB drive.

Answer (score 1):

Apple does not sell an optical media version of El Capitan. You need to use [OS X Recovery](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314) or a USB drive to re-install El Capitan, which is relatively simple to create. All you need is an 8 GB USB drive and a computer running OS X. Instructions on how to create such an installer are here: [How to make a bootable OS X 10.11 El Capitan installer drive](http://www.macworld.com/article/2981585/operating-systems/how-to-make-a-bootable-os-x-10-11-el-capitan-installer-drive.html)

> **Making the installer drive**
>
> 1. Connect to your Mac a properly formatted 8GB (or larger) drive, and rename the drive Untitled. (The Terminal commands I provide here
>      assume that the drive is named Untitled. If the drive isn’t named
>      Untitled, the procedure won’t work.)
> 2. Make sure the El Capitan installer (or at least a copy of it), called Install OS X El Capitan.app, is in its default location in your
>      main Applications folder (/Applications).
> 3. Select the text of the following Terminal command and copy it.
>
>    ```
>    sudo /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ El\ Capitan.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume
>    ```
>
>    /Volumes/Untitled --applicationpath /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ El\
>      Capitan.app --nointeraction
> 4. Launch Terminal (in /Applications/Utilities).
> 5. Warning: This step will erase the destination drive or partition, so make sure that it doesn’t contain any valuable data. Paste the
>      copied command into Terminal and press Return.
> 6. Type your admin-level account password when prompted, and then press Return.
> 7. You may see the message “To continue we need to erase the disk at /Volumes/Untitled. If you wish to continue type (Y) then press
>      return:” If so, type the letter Y and then press Return. If you don't
>      see this message, you're already set.
>
> The Terminal window displays createinstallmedia’s progress as a
>   textual representation of a progress bar: Erasing Disk: 0%... 10
>   percent...20 percent... and so on. You also see a list of the
>   program’s tasks as they occur: Copying installer files to disk... Copy
>   complete. Making disk bootable... Copying boot files... Copy complete.
>   The procedure can take as little as a couple minutes, or as long as 20
>   to 30 minutes, depending on how fast your Mac can copy data to the
>   destination drive. Once you see Copy Complete. Done., as shown in the
>   screenshot above, the process has finished.
>
> Createinstallmedia will have renamed your drive from Untitled to
>   Install OS X El Capitan. You can rename the drive (in the Finder) if
>   you like—renaming it won’t prevent it from working properly.